# I can't jump and move at the same time unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, move

i made 2d character and 3 ui buttons and they worked well

---

but the problem is when moving to the right or left by the ui buttons i can't jump however when jump from the ui button i can move to right and left

---

this is the script

```
public class PlayerWalk : MonoBehaviour {

    private PlayerAnimation playerAnim;
    private Rigidbody2D myBody;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;


    public float speed = 7f;
    public float jumpForce = 7f;

    private bool moveLeft; // determine if we move left or right
    private bool dontMove; // determine if we are moving or not
    private bool canJump; // we will test if we can jump

   

    void Start () {
        playerAnim = GetComponent<PlayerAnimation>();
        myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        dontMove = true;
    }
    
    void Update () {
        //DetectInput();
        HandleMoving();
    }

    void HandleMoving() {

        if (dontMove) {

            StopMoving();

        } else {

            if (moveLeft) {
                
                MoveLeft();

            } else if (!moveLeft) {
                
                MoveRight();

            }

        }

    } // handle moving

    public void AllowMovement(bool movement) {
        dontMove = false;
        moveLeft = movement;
    }

    public void DontAllowMovement() {
        dontMove = true;
    }

    public void Jump() {
        if(canJump) {
            myBody.velocity = new Vector2(myBody.velocity.x, jumpForce);
       //myBody.AddForce(Vector2.right * jumpForce);

        }
    }

    // PREVIOUS FUNCTIONS

    public void MoveLeft() {
        myBody.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, myBody.velocity.y);
        playerAnim.ZombieWalk(true, true);
        
    }

    public void MoveRight() {
        myBody.velocity = new Vector2(speed, myBody.velocity.y);
        playerAnim.ZombieWalk(true, false);
    }

    public void StopMoving() {
        playerAnim.ZombieStop();
        myBody.velocity = new Vector2(0f, myBody.velocity.y);
    }

    void DetectInput() {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (x > 0)
        {
            MoveRight();
        }
        else if (x < 0)
        {
            MoveLeft();
        }
        else
        {
            StopMoving();
        }
    } 
    

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            canJump = true;   
            
        }

        
    }

   void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
       if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
           canJump = false;
       }
   }

} // class
```

---

the 2d character moves well and there is no bugs or problems with scripts

Any help??
I don't know where is the problem??

**Note ** i used unity5.6

Comment: i hope you set the ground gameobject tag to Ground and it has a collider and the player has a collider and non kinematic rigidbody :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say onTriggerEnter2D instead of using onCollisionEnter2D would be a better option in this scenario. You can read more about that here.

[https://answers.unity.com/questions/875770/ontriggerenter-or-oncollisionenter-1.html#:~:text=OnCollisionEnter%20is%20called%20when%20two,with%20%22IsTrigger%22%20set](https://answers.unity.com/questions/875770/ontriggerenter-or-oncollisionenter-1.html#:%7E:text=OnCollisionEnter%20is%20called%20when%20two,with%20%22IsTrigger%22%20set)).

Did you try to debug the value of canJump while you are trying to move left or right?

Comment: thanks for your respond , i tried to make debug and nothing happen

Comment: What value do you get for canJump when clicking on jump button  ( inside the method for jump logic)?

Comment: the can jump function make the jump fun. allowed in event trigger

Comment: I agree. But do you get canJump value as true in that function when you click the jump button?